# Avoid COUNT to CAST to BIGINT

Tags: jpa, db2, jpa-2.0

Using Open JPA 2.0, Database is DB2 9.7. For query like `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM USER WHERE FNAME := fname`, JPA is converting the query to `SELECT COUNT(CAST(? AS BIGINT)) FROM TABLENAME`.
How to avoid the CAST to BIGINT?

Code sample below:

```
query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("qry.checkuser");
query.setParameter("fname", fname); 
Long count = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Can you give your sample code that creates the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is:

```
SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) FROM USER WHERE FNAME := fname
```

Basically we need to use a non nullable column like Primary key column and with this change the CAST can be avoided which consumes additional CPU, a minor gain.

Answer (score 1):

Which one is the problem in the CAST?

I think you can't avoid it since is SQL generated by the JPA provider.

BTW, I allways use Number super class instead of specific subclass:

```
query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("qry.checkuser", Number.class);
query.setParameter("fname", fname); 
Number count = query.getSingleResult();
// Do whatever is needed
if (count.longValue()...
```

This way there's no problem if the JPA provider returns a integer, long or BigXXXX.